# docker push failure getting unhelpful unspecific "unauthorized" message

Tags: docker, jenkins, push, unauthorized

image builds fine and successfully tags.

then the below is logged.

```
f5274dbb265d: Preparing
0c484a3ebe7d: Preparing
a0f976e3bcb6: Preparing
367c87d34790: Preparing
b0be1ac61406: Preparing
7a2766f96db9: Preparing
e5a477b23358: Preparing
e5a477b23358: Waiting
7a2766f96db9: Waiting
367c87d34790: Layer already exists
0c484a3ebe7d: Layer already exists
b0be1ac61406: Layer already exists
a0f976e3bcb6: Layer already exists
f5274dbb265d: Layer already exists
7a2766f96db9: Layer already exists
e5a477b23358: Layer already exists
unauthorized
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas or suggestions to try would be so very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check,

1. Yes, the image builds fine. After that during push some authentication is failing. In the sense with what user u r trying to build and push the image and does it can able to login to target repo?. Does this user able to login to 'docker login' and access the repo successfully?. If yes, then need to check the user authorization on target repo like docker hub or custom repo that you are trying to push.